# JWT parse claims with org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt

Tags: java, spring, jwt, spring-oauth2

I'm using `org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt` library to write a JWT utility class which will be in charge of creating tokens and parsing claims. Now my question is how to I parse claims of my JWT correctly? There seems to far and few examples on the web on how to extract a claim using this library. Any help would be appreciate it

```
@Service
public class JwtUtil {

    public static final String JWT_ISSUER = "test.com";
    public static final long JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRY = 3600L;
    public static final long JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRY = 7200L;

    private JwtEncoder jwtEncoder;

    private String extractExpiresAt(String token) {
        // return expires at claim
    }

    private String createToken(String subject, Consumer<Map<String, Object>> claims) {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        JwtClaimsSet claimsSet = JwtClaimsSet.builder()
                .issuer(JWT_ISSUER)
                .issuedAt(now)
                .expiresAt(now.plusSeconds(JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRY))
                .subject(subject)
                .claims(claims)
                .build();

        return jwtEncoder.encode(JwtEncoderParameters.from(claimsSet)).getTokenValue();
    }

    private String createRefreshToken(String subject) {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        JwtClaimsSet claimsSet = JwtClaimsSet.builder()
                .issuer(JWT_ISSUER)
                .issuedAt(now)
                .expiresAt(now.plusSeconds(JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRY))
                .subject(subject)
                .build();

        return jwtEncoder.encode(JwtEncoderParameters.from(claimsSet)).getTokenValue();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found this area of the Spring Security framework quite opaque. This may not answer the question, but I thought it might help if, like me, you landed here while looking for a way to parse a text JWT into an instance of Springs Jwt class.  There's likely more elegant, "correct" ways, but this gets it done.

You'll need to import an additional JWT lib:

```
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.JWT;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.JWTClaimsSet;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.JWTParser;
```

Then:

```
String token = "YOUR_JWT_TEXT_HERE";

JWT interstitialJwt = JWTParser.parse(token);
JWTClaimsSet jwtClaimsSet = interstitialJwt.getJWTClaimsSet();
Instant issuedAt = jwtClaimsSet.getDateClaim("iat").toInstant();
Instant expiresAt = jwtClaimsSet.getDateClaim("exp").toInstant();

Jwt.Builder jwtBuilder = Jwt.withTokenValue(token);
interstitialJwt.getHeader().toJSONObject().entrySet().stream().forEach((header) -> jwtBuilder.header(header.getKey(), header.getValue()));
jwtClaimsSet.getClaims().entrySet().stream().forEach((claim) -> jwtBuilder.claim(claim.getKey(), claim.getValue()));
jwtBuilder.issuedAt(issuedAt);
jwtBuilder.expiresAt(expiresAt);
Jwt jwt = jwtBuilder.build();
```